How to adapt llama v2 model to less than 7b parameters
Help me please in python
I was trying make llama-2-7b to make it 125 million for laptop users I also tried this but I was facing problem with tokenizer:
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig, AutoTokenizer

# Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 config
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B")

# Modify the config to reduce size
config.hidden_size = 1000
config.num_hidden_layers = 10
config.num_attention_heads = 20

# Instantiate modified model from modified config
smaller_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)

# Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B")

# Adjust tokenizer settings based on modified model configuration
max_length = 512  # Set the appropriate maximum sequence length based on your model modifications
tokenizer.model_max_length = max_length

# Optionally, you may need to adjust other tokenizer settings depending on your modifications
# tokenizer.padding_side = "left"  # Example: Change padding side if necessary

# Update tokenizer.json
tokenizer.save_pretrained("/content")

print("New number of parameters: {:.3f} billion".format(sum(p.numel() for p in smaller_model.parameters()) / 1e9))

Saving Script:
# Move model to GPU if available
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
smaller_model.to(device)

# Define your Hugging Face repository
username = "ar08"  # Replace with your Hugging Face username
repo_name = "Llama-3-1.7B"  # Replace with the name of your Hugging Face repository
token = "***************************"  # Replace with your Hugging Face token

# Save the smaller model to your Hugging Face repository
smaller_model.push_to_hub(username, repo_name, use_auth_token=token)

